# How to divide raster sample based on probabilities into three categories and set the values of these categories in R?

Tags: r, random, raster

Apologies for my question being cumbersome. What I am trying to do is generate a raster where a random 1% of the layer pixels have values, and of these valued pixels, a random 35% have value 1, 55% have value 2, and 10% have value 3. The rest of the pixels should take on the 'no data' marker in R ("NA").

It's easy enough creating a raster with 1% of the pixels with a uniform value using the following code:

```
pixels <- raster(ext = extent(-120, -119, 49, 50), resolution = c(0.001, 0.001), crs = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"), vals = 1)

testing <- sampleRandom(pixels, size = as.integer(0.01*ncell(pixels)), asRaster = TRUE)
```

However, I am unsure how to then divide the valued pixels of `testing` into three categories and set the values of these categories according to the above.

Is this possible, or else another way of achieving what I am after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not too cumbersome,

Function `f` takes the total number of cells

```
f <- function(N) {
    n <- N/100  # 1% sample
    # create a vector with the values you want
    v <- c(rep(1, 0.35*n), rep(2, 0.55*n), rep(3, 0.1*n))
    # sample these values (that is, put them in random order)
    v <- sample(v)
    # create output vector 
    out <- rep(NA, N)
    # put the values in random places
    out[sample(N, length(v))] <- v
    out
}

library(raster)
# create a RasterLayer
r <- raster(ncol=100, nrow=100)
set.seed(10) # for reproducibility
values(r) <- f(ncell(r))
```

Show that it works

```
table(values(r))
# 1  2  3 
#35 55 10
```

Another way would be to use probabilities with sample

```
set.seed(10) 
N <- ncell(r)
v <- sample(3, N/100, prob=c(0.35, 0.55, 0.1), replace=TRUE)
table(v)
# 1  2  3 
#30 67  3
```

But because that uses probabilities, the proportions are not *exact*. In this case it seem far off, but that is because of the small sample size.

Following your example, you could also go along this route

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ext=extent(-120, -119, 49, 50), resolution=c(0.001, 0.001), crs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84", vals = 1)
r <- sampleRandom(r, size = (0.01*ncell(r)), asRaster = TRUE)

sfun <- function(x) {
   i <- !is.na(x)
   x[i] <- sample(1:3, sum(i), prob=c(0.35, 0.55, 0.1), replace=TRUE)
   x
}

set.seed(101)
x <- calc(r, sfun)
```

Again approximately correct

```
tab <- table(values(x))
100 * tab / sum(tab)
#   1     2     3 
#35.45 54.62  9.93
```